# Topic for presentation on Group Representations, Young Tableaux, Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, representation-theory

I need to do a presentation relating to group representations/Young tableaux/symmetric group; however, for all my searching, I cannot find a cool topic that I find personally interesting (and that is presentable in 20 minutes).

As a last-ditch effort, does anyone have any recommendations? I was really hoping to find some cool application of group representation theory or Young tableaux to number theory, graph theory, or geometry. I seem to favor ideas with a geometric feel.

Anyways, thanks for any ideas you have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula
$$
\sum_\lambda d_\lambda^2 = n!
$$
(where the sum is over all partitions $\lambda$ of $n$, and $d_\lambda$ denotes the number of standard fillings) is really cool.  There is a nice proof using Young's lattice.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I love this topic. Do you have a link to the reference for the proof using young lattices? Thanks!